# Get Debug Logs with specified log levels for Execute Anonyous via APEX ToolingAPI (getting Error)

Tags: api, wsdl, tooling

**I imported the Tooling API WSDL back into Apex as toolingSoapSforceCom and added a Remote Site setting from my Salesforce pod/domain.**

```
toolingSoapSforceCom.SforceService toolingService = new toolingSoapSforceCom.SforceService();
toolingService.SessionHeader = new toolingSoapSforceCom.SessionHeader_element();
toolingService.SessionHeader.SessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
toolingService.DebuggingHeader = new toolingSoapSforceCom.DebuggingHeader_element();
toolingService.DebuggingHeader.debugLevel = 'DEBUGONLY';
toolingService.DebuggingHeader.categories = new List< toolingSoapSforceCom.LogInfo>();
toolingSoapSforceCom.LogInfo apexLogInfo = new toolingSoapSforceCom.LogInfo();
apexLogInfo.category='Apex_code';
apexLogInfo.level='FINEST';
toolingService.DebuggingHeader.categories.add(apexLogInfo);
toolingSoapSforceCom.ExecuteAnonymousResult executeResponse = toolingService.executeAnonymous('System.debug(\'hello World\');');
System.assert(executeResponse.compiled);
System.debug(toolingService.DebuggingInfo);
```

**Error Message**

> System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: Destination URL not reset. The URL returned from login must be set in the SforceService faultcode=UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION faultactor=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset the endpoint before you can call the service. The WSDL, by default, points to https://login.salesforce.com/ or https://test.salesforce.com/, but once you have a Session ID, you are expected to hit your local endpoint. The following code should suffice:

```
toolingService.endpoint_x = new URL(
  Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getProtocol(),
  Url.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost(),
  '/services/Soap/T/41.0').toExternalForm();
```

Note that it's probably a lot easier to use the REST API if whatever you're trying to do is in the REST API.

Comment: it works fine, but at the end System.debug(toolingService.DebuggingInfo); lines throws the null value, could you please help me in this.

Comment: @Rehan DebuggingInfo would indeed be null in your object. You need to later query the ApexLog object to get your debug information back.

Answer (score 0):

According to error message, it simply says `Destination URL not reset`. So basically, when you use `login` you will receive SessionId and URL.

That `URL` (destination) must be assigned as an URL.

Comment: How Can I Fix this